# INDEX MATCH function isnt returning more than one match

Tags: excel

I am trying to get an index match funtion to insert 1 to 51 rows depending on one cell and the name picked in that cell from one sheet to another.

The index match function is for now like this in column `AK SiDAQ`: 
`=IFERROR(INDEX(SiDAQ_Template_Move!A3:AO3;;MATCH(SiDAQ!$X$5;SiDAQ_Template_Move!$A$2:$AO$2;));"")`

The index match function is for now like this in column `AL SiDAQ`:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(SiDAQ_Template_Move!A185:AO185;;MATCH(SiDAQ!$X$5;SiDAQ_Template_Move!$A$184:$AO$184;0));"")`

this only replies for the first cell in `X5`  if this cell isnt in `$` then it replies all wrong from the sheet `SiDAQ_Template_Move!`

And also in sheet `SiDAQ` when choosing a name in cell `X5` it insert from sheet `SiDAQ_Template_Move!` the right in the top of columns `AK and AL` in  `SiDAQ` but lower in column `AL` it inserts information equal to the information in `SiDAQ_Template_Move!`  row 185.

i will include pictures in the comment.
[image: SiDAQ sheet]
[image: SiDAQ_Template_Move Sheet]

it can show more than one value in the two columns: 
[image]

but it cant show for one in `X5` and then number two afterwards.
[image]

Comment: INDEX() & MATCH() will return one value, have a search on here for dealing with duplicates...

Comment: i dont understand @SolarMike